# How to pull live data from database in laravel without page refresh

Tags: laravel, data-synchronization

I have to read data from the database and I have to find all the records whose status is Completed, and after then I have to call an **API to generate a report** and at the same time, I have to call another **API which will download the report** for the records whose report get generated in the last API call. All this need to be run in the background asynchronously.

Please suggest to me the best approach to handle this situation because API for generating a report takes negligible time but API for report downloading takes time because of the large data contained in the report.

Note:- **Data will be in GB.**

Comment: If data will be in GB, I recommend you to utilize larvel queue, use laravel queue to generate report and notify user about completion, so that user could download this report.

Comment: To run heavy async tasks in the background you can use Queue system in Laravel.
It allows you to run different tasks (Jobs) in the background, bring them in chains and batches. Pls have a look at this: https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/queues#introduction

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.